# Find the value of $x$ in $3115_x + 4514_x = 10632_x$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems

> Find the value of $x$ in $3115_x + 4514_x = 10632_x$.

I don’t understand how to even begin to go about solving this, because the bases are unknown. I don’t know if I should try tackling the bases first or the actual numbers themselves, and I’m just a bit lost. Any help, please?

Comment: Looking at the ones digits, it appears that $5_x+4_x=12_x$

Comment: Can you explain how you got this please? I have like 7 other similar questions to answer and if I just get the working out down, I’ll have an easier time of it.

Comment: Well, you can't _go down_ in digits without having reached the base limit.

Comment: Take @J.W.Tanner's comment seriously. Try to recall the way addition in a base is done. Where does one start when trying to add two numbers? What would we do if the numbers were decimals? Can $x$ be $10$? If yes, you're done; if no, why? The answer to this "why" helps you solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

We know that $x \ge 7$ since
$6$ occurs by itself.

Write
$3115_x + 4514_x = 10632_x
$
as
$(3+4)x^3+(1+5)x^2+(1+1)x+(5+4)
=x^4+6x^2+3x+2
$
or
$7x^3+6x^2+2x+9
=x^4+6x^2+3x+2
$.

We must have
$9 = 2+x$,
so $x = 7$.

As a check,
$7x^3 = x^4$ for $x = 7$.

Answer (score 3):

The ones digit of $3115_x$ is $5$, and the ones digit of $4514_x$ is $4$.

The ones digit of their sum should be $9$, unless $x
\le9$, in which case it should be $9-x$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Good point, @Joe; thanks; I have edited accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Hint #1: The maximum number in this case is $6$, and you have only the numbers $0-6.$

Hint #2: Make an addition table to find out why $5 + 4 = 12$ and $3 + 4 = 10$ in this base.

Answer (score 1):

THis is just $$(5+x+x^2+3x^3)+(4+x+5x^2+4x^3)=(2+3x+6x^2+x^4)
$$ Thus because of $1+5=6$ (coefficients of $x^2$) and $3+4=0$ (coefficients of $x^3$) the base is $7$.